# Why does my if linked list empty statement not output anything?

Tags: java

I'm writing a game in java and I have an else statement that checks the length of a linked list of objects, and if it is empty, should return "You win" in the console. Using breakpoints in intelliJ I can see that the code is being executed on each tick of the game, but it never seems to register the condition as true.

The game is a simple rhythm game where the player has to time their button presses to score points, and whether the player misses, or hits the beat, the first instance of the object type is removed from the linked list, so theoretically the list should be empty if the player wins the game. and the console does output a "no such element" exception when checking for beats after the last one is missed or hit.

From this I know that the code is executing and that the linked list is empty. I've also tried several methods for checking whether the linked list is empty.

```
public void checkBeats(){
        Beat currentObject = (Beat) Game.beatLinkedList.getFirst();
        //Find the x position of the current object
        int currentBeatPosition = currentObject.getX();

        //Condition to award points to the player if they time hitting the beat correctly
        if (currentBeatPosition <= 70) {
            //Add 100 to the score variable.
            Player.lives -= 1;
            Game.beatLinkedList.removeFirst();
            for (GameObject obj : Handler.object) {
                if (obj instanceof Beat) {
                    Handler.object.remove(obj);
                    break;
                }
            }
            checkLives();
        }

        else if (beatLinkedList.isEmpty() == true){
            System.out.println("YOU WIN");
        }
    }
```

I have also used `beatLinkedList.size ==0`, and a few others such as `if null` and nothing seems to work. Would appreciate it if anyone knew why.

Edit:

Tried with removing the `else`, and changed `Game.beatLinkedList` to just `beatLinkedList`, as I am working within the `Game` class anyway.

```
public void checkBeats(){
    Beat currentObject = (Beat) beatLinkedList.getFirst();
    //Find the x position of the current object
    int currentBeatPosition = currentObject.getX();

    //Condition to award points to the player if they time hitting the beat correctly
    if (currentBeatPosition <= 70) {
        //Add 100 to the score variable.
        Player.lives -= 1;
        Game.beatLinkedList.removeFirst();
        for (GameObject obj : Handler.object) {
            if (obj instanceof Beat) {
                Handler.object.remove(obj);
                break;
            }
        }
        checkLives();
    }

    if (beatLinkedList.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

If I change the code to   `if (beatLinkedList.size() == 1)` Then when it reaches the second to last beat, the you win message prints several times in the console, not sure what is going on when it reaches 0.

Comment: Maybe you don't want `else if` - just an `if` - so that it checks `isEmpty()` everytime?

Comment: Please provide all the relevant classes at stake so that we can really help you. Otherwise there is no way we call tell what is wrong with your code. Currently, there are so many open questions: where does `beatLinkedList` come from? What is `checkLives()` doing? What are `Beat`, `Game`, `GameObject` and `Handler`?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be, that when the list is empty empty also the first contortion (`currentBeatPosition <= 70`) is true?

If so, you won't get into the "else" if block in the first place.

In that case just make it

```java
if (beatLinkedList.isEmpty() == true){
     System.out.println("YOU WIN");
}
```

(Drop the "else")

Comment: As far as I know it shouldn't be possible as the x value received is an attribute of the beat object, but I'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Change the *else if* to and *if*. That way it will check everytime if the players has won.

Second Your code inside the else if might be wrong(?) in almost every line you interact with your *beatLinkedList* you type **Game.** infront. However, in your if else you don't use **Game.BeatlinkedList**, you only use *beatLinkedList*. Any reason for this?

```
if (Game.beatLinkedList.isEmpty()){ //you don't need == true.
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing that out, I realised the Game. in the checkBeats() method was not necessary, I'll update the question with the current code too.